# Riak-cs solution with antivirus

Tags: riak, riak-cs

Does riacks offer any feature of virus scanning, or can an easy software be implemented on top ?

I did not find anything on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Riak KV, TS, and S2 (formerly C2) do not offer any anti virus scanning functionality. You will need to implement your own anti virus capability in front of whichever Riak you use.